# How can i find patterns in text?

Tags: c++

my problem is that my code used to find patterns in words find "pattern" letter by letter. (My goal is to use my code to find whole patterns in one word, for example, for word "abcabcabc" and pattern "abc" i would like to achive result of "3".)

There is my code

```
   case 2:{
            string text, pattern;
            int a, b;
            int counter = 0;
            cin >> text >> pattern;

            for (a = 0; a < text.size(); a++) {
                for (b = 0; b < pattern.size(); b++) {
                    if (text[a] == pattern[b])
                        counter++;
                }
            }
            cout << counter;
            break;
         }
```

Comment: Check this link if its helpful- [https://www.techiedelight.com/count-number-times-pattern-appears-given-string-subsequence/](https://www.techiedelight.com/count-number-times-pattern-appears-given-string-subsequence/)

Comment: From earlier today [How do I check if a pattern exists in an entered string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60763235/3422102) - C, but on point.Or simply use [std::basic_string::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the question is asking about the count of patterns, so string::find won't work.

Comment: Sure it will, it returns the `index` to the start of the patter, so you just keep an offset and work down the string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the number of occurrences of a string within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489073/counting-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Aah I see, I thought you meant in a single call.

Comment: Yes, kinda like this one [Number of vowels in string of characters C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613617/number-of-vowels-in-string-of-characters-c/54614087?r=SearchResults&s=8|19.3807#54614087)

Answer (score 0):

There are two well known general purpose algorithms:
[Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)
[Boyer–Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm)

If you need something more special, Wikipedia might help to find a direction where to start:
(String matching algorithms)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_matching_algorithms]